# Why is the electric potential formula like this and how is it derived?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, field-theory

So from what I could understand from my Electrical Engineering lectures the electric potential at a particular point charge $A$ is:

$$u_A=-\int_{\infty}^{r_A}\vec E\cdot d\vec r$$

The minus here might be a mistake on my side because I think since they're still written in vector form the minus should not be there. Not sure though.

But how is this formula derived? Why is it particularly the line integral of $\vec E\cdot d\vec r$? Btw I'm a beginner in this field so please go easy with the electrical engineering jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Electric potential could be defined as the (opposite of the) work done on a charge by the electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$, per unit charge.

The force exerted on a charge $q$ by the electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ can be written as $\mathbf{F} = \frac{\mathbf{E}}{q}$.

The work done by the electric field on a charge $q$ while along a path $\ell$ joining two points $\mathbf{r}_0$, $\mathbf{r}_1$, as the line integral of the dot product of the force $\mathbf{F}$ and the infinitesimal displacement $d \mathbf{r}$,

$W = \displaystyle \int_{\ell} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = q \int_{\ell} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$.

In electrostatics, the electric field can be written as the gradient of a scalar field $\varphi(\mathbf{r})$, $\mathbf{E} = - \nabla \varphi$, so that the last integral doesn't depend on the actual path $\ell$, but only on its extreme points $\mathbf{r}_0$, $\mathbf{r}_1$,

$W = \displaystyle \int_{\ell} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = q \int_{\ell} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = - q \int_{\ell} \nabla \varphi \cdot d\mathbf{r} = - q \int_{\mathbf{r}_0}^{\mathbf{r}_1} d\varphi = - q \Delta\varphi \bigg|_{\mathbf{r}_0}^{\mathbf{r}_1} = - q (\varphi(\mathbf{r}_1)-\varphi(\mathbf{r}_0))$.

What it really matters here is the difference between the value of the scalar field $\varphi(\mathbf{r})$ evaluated in the extreme points, thus we can only define the scalar field up to an additive constant, i.e. we would get the same results if we define the scalar field as $\tilde{\varphi}(\mathbf{r}) = \varphi(\mathbf{r}) + c$.

Many times we deal with vanishing fields at the infinity, and it's a common choice to define the additive constant $c$ in order to set $\lim_{|\mathbf{r}| \rightarrow \infty}\varphi(\mathbf{r}) \rightarrow 0$. If we do so and let $|\mathbf{r}_0| \rightarrow \infty$, we get

$\displaystyle W = q \int_{\ell} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \lim_{|\mathbf{r}_0| \rightarrow \infty} q \int_{\mathbf{r}_0 }^{\mathbf{r}_1} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \dots = - q \varphi(\mathbf{r}_1)$,

and thus

$\displaystyle \varphi(\mathbf{r}_1) = - \int_{"\infty"}^{\mathbf{r}_1} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r} $

where the lower extreme of the integral means that you can choose any point at infinity where the potential $\phi(\mathbf{r}_{"\infty"}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The electric potential $u(\vec{r})$ is defined in such a way that $\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} u$.  And the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) from multivariable calculus says that the difference between $u$ at two points $\vec{r}_A$ and $\vec{r}_B$ is given by
$$
u(\vec{r}_B) - u(\vec{r}_A) = \int_{\vec{r}_A}^{\vec{r}_B} (\vec{\nabla} u) \cdot d\vec{r} = - \int_{\vec{r}_A}^{\vec{r}_B} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{r}.
$$
By convention, we take $u(\infty) = 0$, and apply the above formula using $\vec{r}_A = \infty$ (abusing notation a bit there.)

In other words, you can find $\vec{E}$ (given $u$) by taking the negative gradient, and you can find $u$ (given $\vec{E}$) by taking the negative line integral.  The two operations are inverses of each other in multi-variable calculus, just as integration and differentiation are inverses of each other in regular old single-variable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

The negative sign over here is purely for conventional purposes.

As for the question of derivation, this term is not derived but rather defined. The motivation is that since the electric field, is a vector field, it becomes a "natural" mathematical step to consider its line integral. However, from a physical point of view, you'll realize that it becomes sensible to define such a quantity by analyzing the work done in an electrostatic field.

Comment: Here is a perfectly correct answer relevant to the question; so why is it downvoted? As a matter of basic common politeness this should be explained for it not only is insulting but also misleads the questioner with the false claim to  be wrong when in fact is not. Or if it is wrong, then explain why so? Of course, one can always say that the answer by @basics is more informative, and it is, but downvoting implies that this one is incorrect not that there are better ways of answering.

Comment: @hyportnex I agree with you that every downvote should be explained. I'm quite new to SE, but I can say that downvote without a comment at least, is one of the behavior that drives me crazy. Talking about this very answer, it looks quite a bad answer, imho. Anyway, I didn't downvote this time, as I've already done to some gedanken answers and questions in the past